# SyntaxError: 'await' outside function | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

*I know - there are a lot of questions with this title, but most are for Dark Sky or are different to my problem.*

```
class Counter(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='0', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def counter(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: 
    discord.Interaction):
        number = int(button.label)
        button.label = str(number + 1)
        if number + 1 >= 5:
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green

        await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

view = Counter()
await ctx.send('Press to increment', view=view)
```

Error message:

```
  File "main.py", line 27
    await ctx.send('Press to increment', view=view)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

I'm very new to python and am not sure why this is at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the last line is not inside an async function, put it inside an async function, it would work

Comment: `await` is advanced Python and you said you are new to Python. That makes it difficult to help.

Comment: full code pls...

Comment: @VPfB I think the fact is, lots of people are getting into python (and programming in general) with Discord.py, which requires learning at least a surface level understanding of async programming. Saying it's too advanced doesn't help people--there's always going to be people diving in the deep and, and tbh it's probably the best way to learn

Answer (score 0):

The typical structure of your code will be ([using sample code from the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#commands))

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

That's also where the `ctx` you're using comes from--if you removed the await you'd get an error that `ctx` wasn't defined. Your code will specify functions that correspond to commands or other events on discord, and discord.py will handle calling the functions you specify when users perform those actions.

You can only use the `await` keyword in `async` functions. The idea behind these functions is that if your code has to do something that takes a long time, but mostly just involves waiting, python can go do other stuff while it waits. For discord.py, since a lot of your operations involve waiting for slow network operations like sending messages, that's very important.

[here's one intro to the ideas behind async/await](https://dev.to/code_enzyme/introduction-to-using-async-await-in-python-2i0n), I haven't read it too much, so if it's bad or anybody has better suggestions drop a link in the comments.

Comment: The linked discussion is about await in javascript, not in Python.

Comment: aw jeez. good catch

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the

```py
view = Counter()
await ctx.send('Press to increment', view=view)
```

code inside a asynchron function, because the `await` keyword can only be used inside of asynchron functions.

example functions

```py
async def my_function(): # this is an async function
   ...
def my_other_function(): # this is a normal function
   ...
```

Async functions have to be called with the `await` keyword, or else you'll get an exception

```py
await my_function() # calling an async function
my_other_function() # calling a normal function
```

as you can see in this example, in the async function, you can use `await`

```py
async def something():
    print("hello async world")

async def my_function():
    await something()
```

but if you try to await an async function inside a normal function

```py
asnyc def something():
    print("hello async world")
def my_other_function():
    await something()
```

You will get the `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function` error

---

The best way to do this together with a discord bot is by adding the code to a listener. For example with the `on_message` event which will be fired whenever a message is incoming

Example for on_message event

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message): # The event
    if message.content == "your_text" # Insert a text here that is needed to use the "command"
        # your code will be executed whenever the bot receives a message with the content "your_text"
        view = Counter()
        await message.channel.send('Press to increment', view=view)
client.run("your unique token here")
```

I would recommend to take a look at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html before starting

According to the `ctx`, your code is made for the client's `@commands.command` function.

(this should fix your code)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

class Counter(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='0', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def counter(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: 
    discord.Interaction):
        number = int(button.label)
        button.label = str(number + 1)
        if number + 1 >= 5:
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.green

        await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

@bot.command("test")
async def command(ctx):
    view = Counter()
    await ctx.send('Press to increment', view=view)

bot.run("your unique token here")
```

In order to use your code, you need to send a message in a channel where your bot can read messages with the content `!test` to invoke the command